# Going from a flat stucture to a hierarchy using jsonata

Tags: jsonata

I am tryig to use jsonata to to transform a flat json result set to something that aggregates some items and creates arrays.

Any advice on how I go from a source like this
`

```
{
  "name": "myname",
  "payload": [
    {
      "role": "Testrole 1",
      "permission": "Testpermission 1"
    },
    {
      "role": "Testrole 1",
      "permission": "Testpermission 2"
    },
    {
      "role": "Testrole 2",
      "permission": "Testpermission 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

`

to a target like this
`

```
{
  "name": "myname",
  "roles": [
    {
      "rolename": "Testrole 1",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "permissionname": "Testpermission 1"
        },
        {
          "permissionname": "Testpermission 2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "rolename": "Testrole 2",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "permissionname": "Testpermission 3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

`

I've checked the jsonata documentation but cannot find a good way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [reduce operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#---reduce) to group by a role as described in the Grouping docs [here](https://docs.jsonata.org/sorting-grouping#grouping), and then map it to your desired shape:

```
{
  "name": name,
  "roles": payload{
    role: permission
  } ~> $each(function($permissions, $role) {
    { 
      "rolename": $role, 
      "permissions": $permissions.{ "permissionname": $ }
    }
  })
}
```

Live example on the playground: https://stedi.link/WFEPgxp